# Why .freeze and .dup SomeGem::VERSION?

Tags: rubygems

While I was reading https://github.com/thoughtbot/high_voltage source code, I found in gem spec file:

```ruby
Gem::Specification.new do |s|
  s.name        = 'high_voltage'
  s.version     = HighVoltage::VERSION.dup
```

and in `lib/high_voltage/version.rb` file:

```ruby
module HighVoltage
  VERSION = "2.2.1".freeze
end
```

What is the benefit of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to http://alexpeattie.com/blog/defining-versions-in-ruby-gems/, it makes the string immutable so it isn't accidentally changed.